# A step in proof of a theorem about prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to understand some lines in the proof of following theorem, which I am not getting.

**Theorem:** Let $\mathfrak{p}_i$ ($i=1,2,\ldots,d$) be prime ideals in a commutative ring $A$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ be any ideal. If for some $y\in A$, $y+\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^d \mathfrak{p}_i$, then $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_i$ for some $i$.

Here are few lines of the proof.

Since $y=y+0$, so it is in some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_i$.

Case 1. Assume that $y$ is in some, but not all prime ideals, say
$$
y\in \mathfrak{p}_1\cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{p}_j, \,\,\,\, y\notin \mathfrak{p}_{j+1}\cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak{p}_d.
$$
Assume that no prime ideals are contained in other prime ideals here.

Choose $x\in \mathfrak{a}\cap \mathfrak{p}_{j+1}\cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{p}_d$ with $x\notin \mathfrak{p}_1\cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak{p}_j$.

Then $y+x\in\cup_i \mathfrak{p}_i$, contradiction.

**Question:** I do not get why we can guarantee the existence of $x$ with requirement in last but second step?

---

**Ref:** Lecture notes on Local Rings, by Iversen, Page 3,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $l\in\{1,...,d\}$ choose $\alpha_l \in \mathfrak{a}\setminus\mathfrak{p}_l$.  This is possible because otherwise $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_l$ for some $l$ and the proof of the theorem is complete.

For each $k,l\in\{1,...,d\}$ such that $k\neq l$ choose $\beta_{kl}\in\mathfrak{p}_k\setminus\mathfrak{p}_l$.  This is possible because of the non-containment assumption on the prime ideals.

For each $l\in\{1,...,d\}$ let $$\gamma_l=\prod_{k\neq l}\beta_{kl}$$
Then $\gamma_l\not\in\mathfrak{p}_l$ but $\gamma_l\in\mathfrak{p}_k$ for $k\neq l$.

For each $l\in\{1,...,j\}$ let $$x_l=\alpha_l\prod_{k=j+1}^d \beta_{kl}$$
Then $x_l\in\mathfrak{a}\cap \mathfrak{p}_{j+1}\cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{p}_d$ but $x_l\not\in\mathfrak{p}_l$.

Now let $$x=\sum_{l=1}^j \gamma_l x_l$$
Then $x\in\mathfrak{a}\cap \mathfrak{p}_{j+1}\cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{p}_d$ and $x\notin\mathfrak{p}_1\cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak{p}_j$.

Comment: After choosing $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_l$ as in first line, I think we can take $x:=x_1x_2\cdots x_l$. This will not require CRT. Now, question is: why this choice of $x_i$'s is possible? (It may be trivial, but it is not clicking to me).

Comment: I've reengineered the proof to drop reference to the CRT.  It didn't apply anyway because the $\mathfrak{p}_l$ are not assumed to be co-prime which is a necessary condition in the CRT.  The new proof uses a similar technique to what's used to prove the CRT, but achieves the result without assuming the prime ideals are co-prime.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to define $\displaystyle\gamma_l:=\alpha_l\prod_{k\ne l}\beta_{kl}$? Then $\gamma_l\in\mathfrak a\cap\mathfrak p_{j+1}\cap\cdots\cap\mathfrak p_d$ for every $l\in\{1,\ldots,j\},$ so $\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^j\gamma_l\in\mathfrak a\cap\mathfrak p_{j+1}\cap\cdots\cap\mathfrak p_d$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^j\gamma_l\notin\mathfrak p_1\cup\cdots\cup\mathfrak p_j,$ otherwise, if $\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^j\gamma_l\in\mathfrak p_i,$ for some $1\le i\le j,$ we would have $\displaystyle\gamma_i=\sum_{l=1}^j\gamma_l-\sum_{l=1\\l\ne i}^j\gamma_l\in\mathfrak p_i,$ contradiction.